# Maximal subalgebras in polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

**Question.** What are the maximal subalgebras of polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ over the field of real numbers?

Comment: First of all, are you sure that such maximal subalgebra exist?

Comment: Yes, for example, $A_{p_1, p_2}=\{f\in \mathbb{R}[x]\colon f(p_1)=f(p_2)\},$ where $p_1\ne p_2.$

Comment: Also, $\mathbb{R}[x^2, x^3]$. Is there any specific reason you choose to look over $\mathbb{R}$, rather than $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: All $K$-subalgebras of $K[x]$ are finitely generated, see Gale, Proc AMS 1957, https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-05/S0002-9939-1957-0091273-0/

Comment: The classification should be intepretable in terms of singularities. The first case $A_{p_1,p_2}$ consists in gluing two points in a transverse way. The second case $K[x^2,X^3]$ corresponds to a non-transverse singularity. Isolated singularities of curves are certainly well-classified so as to fully answer the question.

Comment: Is it obviously true that any maximal subalgebra is of codimension $1$ as a vector space? Because if so, then the family $K[(x-a)^2, (x-a)^3 - b(x-a)]$ (which consists of $A_{p_1, p_2}$ and translates of $K[x^2,x^3]$) exhausts all possibilities.

Comment: @user44191 It's not exactly a translate. Translation reduces to $a=0$, then homothety reduces to $b=0,1$ (or to $b=0,\pm 1$ in the real case).

Comment: @YCor Call the algebra $B_{a, b}$; then $B_{a,b} = A_{a + \sqrt{b}, a - \sqrt{b}}$ (assuming we're looking over a quadratically complete field). Translates are only needed for the case $b = 0$, in which case no homothety is needed.

Comment: user44191, over $\mathbb{R},$ since I'm interested in maximal subalgebras of ring $\{a_1f+\ldots+a_nf^n\colon a_1,\ldots, a_n\in\mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N}\},$ where  $f$ is a continuous $\mathbb{R}$-valued function.

Comment: @user44191 thanks for the clarification

Comment: user44191, " if so, then the family K[(x−a)2,(x−a)3−b(x−a)] " --- why? (For case $\mathbb{R}.$)

Comment: @VadimSidorov That family exhausts all codimension $1$ subalgebras. Consider $K[x]$ as an algebra filtered by degree, $K[x] = \cup K[x]^n$. Then $B \cap K[x]^1$ cannot have dimension $2$ (as then $B$ would equal $K[x]$, so it must be dimension $1$. $B \cap K[x]^2$ must have dimension $2$, so it must include $x^2 - 2ax + c$ for some $a, c$. We can adjust by any constant (because constants are in $B$) so this is $x^2 - 2ax + a^2$. Similarly, $B$ must include some monic cubic, and thus can be adjusted to be in the above form.

Comment: @VadimSidorov Then any element of $K[x]$ can be generated by any quadratic and any cubic, up to adding a linear term. Therefore this is true for any element of $B$. But if the linear term is nonzero, then that linear term is in $B$, and so $B$ would be all of $K[x]$ - a contradiction. So all of $B$ is generated by the monic and cubic.

Comment: This is getting somewhat extended; I've made a chat room. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86644/discussion-of-https-mathoverflow-net-questions-316933-maximal-subalgebras-in-po

Comment: user44191, what are the maximal subalgebras $\mathbb{R}[x]x$ --- the ring of polynomials without constant term over the field of real numbers? (We do not require the subalgebra to contain 1; clarify that nonempty subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}[x]x$ be a subalgebra if $f+g, fg, rf\in A$ for any $f, g\in A$ and any $r\in\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: I think this idea should work (but needs fleshing out, in a way that I don't have experience with): For $g \in K[x]$, define $B_g := \{c + g(x) h(x)|h \in K[x]\}$. It's clear that $B_g$ is an algebra. Then: If $B$ is a maximal subalgebra, it can't be of the form $K[g]$, as then $B \subsetneq B_g$. This should imply that the corresponding curve $\mathcal{C}_B$ has singularities. Choose one singularity; this corresponds to some ideal in $K[x]$, and so some $g \in K[x]$. Then it should be possible to prove $B \subseteq B_g$, so $B = B_g$. Finally, unless $g$ is quadratic, $B_g$ isn't maximal.